# How do I get BrainTree transparent redirect to work with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest, payment, braintree

I am using [BrainTree gem](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby) to implement a Transparent Redirect solution. When I run a [sample application](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby_examples), it works, but when I try seemingly the same code in my application, this is the error I get: `expected query string to have an http_status param`

In the code, this error refers to `@result = Braintree::TransparentRedirect.confirm(request.query_string)`

When I output the value of `request.query_string` all I get is `""`

Could you help me figure out what I am missing, and/or where the request is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the redirect_url in a hidden param?

```
tr_data = Braintree::TransparentRedirect.transaction_data(
  :redirect_url => "http://example.com/url_to_redirect_to",
  :transaction => {
    :type => "sale",
    :amount => "10.00"
  }
)

<input type="hidden" name="tr_data" value="<%= ERB::Util.html_escape tr_data %>" />
```

There's more info in [Braintree's docs](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/docs/ruby/transactions/create_tr).

Comment: Yes I was. Still not sure why it wasn't working. I just started the project from scratch and copied BT's sample code over - seems to work now. I'll just stick with it.